# ASP.NET with HTML forms and send, post, get, ajax things

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, post

I do not know exactly where should I start, I have something and some question and some stupid solution which I found, and I do not have enough English to explain myself ):
First of all I just know asp.net web forms with c# and write project with them, but I do not know why I hate asp elmenets and it's postback stuff etc...

Because of that I try to use html elements and of course some problems starts again, these are my points which I want to ask then learn.

I'll share some code below that I want to learn these are right way.

First, In the page some `selected change` or some list `click` I have to change some lists, etc... Even I use for `form` `submit` whithout use `<form>` tags.

In this example I have a list which has button and click them (`'.codes'`) it fills datatable's ('#table_codes') items.

HTML

```
<!--buttons-->
 <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default codes" data-code="01"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Code.Text") %> 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default codes" data-code="02"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Code.Text") %> 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default codes" data-code="03"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Code.Text") %> 3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default codes" data-code="04"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Code.Text") %> 4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default codes" data-code="05"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Code.Text") %> 5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default codes" data-code="06"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Code.Text") %> 6</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default codes" data-code="07"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Code.Text") %> 7</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default codes" data-code="08"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Code.Text") %> 8</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default codes" data-code="09"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Code.Text") %> 9</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default codes" data-code="10"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Code.Text") %> 10</button>
</div>

<!--datatable-->
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-advance table-hover" id="table_codes">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>&nbsp;<%=GetLocalResourceObject("CodeName.Text") %>
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-1">
                <a class="btn default btn-xs green modal-add display-hide" href="#add-code" data-toggle="modal">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;<%=GetLocalResourceObject("BtnAdd.Text") %></a>
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-1">&nbsp;
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Empty.Text") %></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


//Javascript
$(document).on('click', '.btn.codes', function () {
    var $code = $(this).attr('data-code');
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Codes.aspx/Load_Codes",
                data: '{flag: ' + flag + ',code: "' + $code + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var list = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    $('#table_codes-deleted tbody').find("tr").remove();
                    $('#table_codes tbody').find("tr").remove();
                    $.each(list, function (i, item) {
                        var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                                  $('<td class=highlight>').append(item.name),
                                  $('<td>').html((flag == 1 ? '<a class="btn default btn-xs green recover" data-id=' + item.id + ' data-name=' + item.name + '><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> ' + _recover + '</a>' : '<a class="btn default btn-xs purple edit" data-id=' + item.id + ' data-name=' + item.name + '><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> ' + _edit + '</a>')),
                                  $('<td>').html('<a class="btn default btn-xs black delete' + (flag == 1 ? "-deleted" : "") + '" data-id=' + item.id + ' ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> ' + _delete + '</a>')
                                          ).appendTo('#table_codes' + (flag == 1 ? "-deleted" : "") + ' tbody');
                    });
                    if (flag == 1)
                        $('.modal-add').hide();
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('err')
                }
            });
});
```

C#

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Load_Codes(int flag, string code)
{
    ClassDoc classDocument = new ClassDoc();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = classDoc.Code_Load(flag, code).Tables[0];

    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;

    List<CodesDTO> List = new List<CodesDTO>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        CodesDTO codes = new CodesDTO();
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        codes.id = Convert.ToInt64(dr["ID"].ToString());
        codes.name = dr["Name"].ToString();
        List.Add(codes);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(List);
}
```

I know it is a bit more crowded but this is logical and safe? I have delete buttons on it in datatables.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.btn.delete', function () {
    var $id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Codes.aspx/SetVariables",
        data: '{id: "' + $id + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#delete-user').modal('toggle').parent();
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('err')
        }
    });

});

$(document).on('click', '#btn-delete', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Codes.aspx/Delete",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var i = data.d;
            if (i > 0)
                $('.alert-deleted').show();
            else
                $('.alert-failure-deleted').show();
            $('#delete-user').modal('hide');
            privateCodes.handleCodeList(0);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
});


    public class CodesDTO
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Int64 id { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static void SetVariables(int id)
    {
        Codes.id = id;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static int Delete_Code()
    {
        int result = 0;
        if (Codes.id != 0 && Codes.code != "")
        {
            ClassDoc classDoc = new ClassDoc();
            result = classDoc.Code_Delete(Codes.id, Codes.code);
            if (result > 0)
                Codes.id = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Now, firstly this time I send id before the delete action, I thought I could be safier.

I know it's too long but finally I want to learn it is safe and logical for forms?

HTML

```
<div class="form-group"> 
 <label>
    <input type="text" name="view" />
    <%=GetLocalResourceObject("View.Text") %>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="text" name="insert" />
    <%=GetLocalResourceObject("Insert.Text") %>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="text" name="update" />
    <%=GetLocalResourceObject("Update.Text") %>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="text" name="delete" />
    <%=GetLocalResourceObject("Delete.Text") %>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="text" name="download" />
    <%=GetLocalResourceObject("Download.Text") %>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="text" name="upload" />
    <%=GetLocalResourceObject("Upload.Text") %>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="text" name="revision" />
    <%=GetLocalResourceObject("Revision.Text") %>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="text" name="foldercreate" />
    <%=GetLocalResourceObject("Create.Text") %>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="flag" />
    <%=GetLocalResourceObject("lag.Text") %>
</label>
</div>
 <div class="actions">
    <a href="#" class="btn red-sunglo btn-sm" id="btnSave">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp; <%=GetLocalResourceObject("btnSave") %> </a>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function () {
    setPermission($folder, $role)
});

var setPermission = function (folder, role) {

    var _view = $("input[type='text'][name='view']").val()
        , _insert = $("input[type='text'][name='insert']").val()
        , _update = $("input[type='text'][name='update']").val()
        , _delete = $("input[type='text'][name='delete']").val()
        , _download = $("input[type='text'][name='download']").val()
        , _upload = $("input[type='text'][name='upload']").val()
        , _revision = $("input[type='text'][name='revision']").val()
        , _foldercreate = $("input[type='text'][name='foldercreate']").val()
        , _flag = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='flag']").is(":checked")
    ;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "List.aspx/Set",
        data: '{folder: "' + folder +
              '",role: "' + role +
              '",flag: "' + _flag +
              '",view: "' + _view +
              '",insert: "' + _insert +
              '",update: "' + _update +
              '",delete: "' + _delete +
              '",download: "' + _download +
              '",upload: "' + _upload +
              '",revision: "' + _revision +
              '",foldercreate: "' + _foldercreate + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var getPerm = data.d;
            if (getPerm > 1) {
                $('.alert-success-check').slideDown();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.alert-success-check').slideUp();
                }, 3000);
                $('#tree_folder').jstree('refresh');
            } else {
                $('.alert-failure').slideDown();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.alert-failure').slideUp();
                }, 3000);
            }

        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
            $('.alert-failure').slideDown();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.alert-failure').slideUp();
            }, 3000);
        }
    });


}
```

C#

```
[WebMethod]
public static int Set(Int64 folder, Int64 role, bool flag, string view, string insert, string update, string delete, string download, string upload, string revision, string foldercreate)
{
    ClassDoc classDoc = new ClassDoc();
    return classDocu.Set(role, folder, flag, view, insert, update, delete, download, upload, revision, foldercreate);
}
```

I do not know how it looks like, I just want to know how should I make it easier and safier. I discovered accidently when I put into `<form>` tag all `input`s and `button` with type `submit`, it does postback with querystring. I saw or heard before I could post them directly form action or via javascript serialise but I could not find how?

I hope, I could be clear, I just want to learn right way. Especially the form logic and way does not look right for me eventough I use it and now I have more than 40 inputs in a single form and I am looking for right simple way...

Comment: `anybody`
`nobody`
`lolbody`

Comment: For such type of development Asp.Net MVC is a suitable frame work. In MVC you can easily post form data as an Object (called Model) using JavaScript serialize.You can also have forms as per your need. Also In MVC there is no issue of postback, viewstate server controls and their events.

Comment: I do not know ASP.NEt MVC, I just can writ in webforms. Altough I want to learn MVC, our project is built with webforms, and learning mvc will take some more time...